# Image Dropping Down in MultiRow Table

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, multirow

I am trying to build a table of images in Latex. Two of my images are portrait, two are landscape. My end goal, is to have them look like this:

```
|   | B |   |
| A |---| D |
|   | C |   |
```

With my code being:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_back.eps}} & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_side.eps} & \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_front.eps}} \\
& \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_side2.eps} & \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

However, the end result of my table is

```
|   | B |   |
|   |---|   |
| A | C | D |
  A       D
```

Where the A and D image drop below the bottom of the table!

Comment: Do you need `multirow`? Can't you just have parboxes with line breaks?

Comment: there is no NEED to use multirow - how would one do this with parboxes?

Comment: I'd make the paragraphs of type `p{...}` and then just use an ordinary line break (`\\`) between the two landscape pictures.

Comment: I am trying, but can't seem to get the 2 images that should be on top of one another to stack:  `\begin{tabular}{|c|p{1in}|c|}

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_back.eps} & 
\makebox[0.25\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_side.eps} \linebreak\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_side2.eps}} & 
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./2_ACES/images/widiStructures/h_front.eps} 

\end{tabular}`

Comment: What if you do it without the `\makebox`? You're already in a paragraph context there.

Comment: without the makebox it does the new line correctly - but I end up getting those two small images to be bottom aligned, and it extends the table height too far so i geting the B/C images looking like A and D above:

Comment: This might be possible to do with `floatrow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\WideFig}{\fbox{\parbox{1.5in}{WIDE \\ FIGURE}}}%
\newcommand*{\TallFig}{\fbox{\parbox{1.0in}{.\\ VERY\\ VERY\\ VERY\\ VERY \\ TALL \\ FIGURE\\ }}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
    \centering
    \WideFig
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \TallFig

    \TallFig
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
    \centering
    \WideFig
  \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find that the ConTeXt syntax is much nicer for even slightly complicated table layouts. This example is a case in point:

```
\useMPlibrary[dum] % For dummy figures

% Specify the dimensions of figures
\defineexternalfigure[potrait]  [height=6cm, width=3cm]
\defineexternalfigure[landscape][height=3cm, width=3cm]

\starttext

\bTABLE[offset=none]
  \bTR
     \bTD[nr=2] \externalfigure[dum][potrait]   \eTD
     \bTD       \externalfigure[dum][landscape] \eTD
     \bTD[nr=2] \externalfigure[dum][potrait]   \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
     \bTD       \externalfigure[dum][landscape] \eTD
  \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]