# Placing a figure inside a multirow table cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, multirow, tkz-collection

Is it possible to place a figure within a multirow cell? The vertical alignment is ruined. Does it have to do anything with tikz's bounding boxes?

The following mwe produces the following result

[image]

### Edit

Clarification after Gonzalo Medina's answer.

Why is it necessary to restrict the `width` of the figure? The figure is a box. Is it not possible to just fit this box in the merged cell? I have some figures that have to be rather big in order to be viewable.

### Edit 2

After G.M.'s comment I realized that `multirow` works only horizontally and not vertically. Unfortunately, I can't make the figures much smaller because they don't look nice. So I have to increase the height of the unmerged rows.

Perhaps a work around would be to calculate the height of the *.pdf, divide it by the number of unmerged rows and use `\vphantom{}` on the unmerged cells to increase their height. Or some kind of a box. Probably increasing the `arraystretch` would work too if there are no rows without figures.

Is there a more robust way to handle this sitution?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabu}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Sections & Axis & Imperfections\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{circular_hollow.pdf}} & $y-y$ & $\dfrac{L}{200}$ \\
                                                                               & $z-z$ & $\dfrac{L}{150}$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`circular_hollow.pdf` is produced by the following file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tkz-tab,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all} % all the objects

\usepackage[xetex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{pgfpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\tkzInit[xmin=-4.5, xmax=4.5, ymin=-4.5, ymax=4.5]
\useasboundingbox(-4.5, -4.5) rectangle (4.5, 4.5);

% Concrete and steel section
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 0/3/R}
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=black!10,line width=8pt](O,R)

% Steel Rebars + Stirrups
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 0/2.3/R}
\tkzDrawCircle[fill=black!30,line width=2pt](O,R)

\foreach \a in {0,30,...,360}{%
    \tkzDefPoint(\a:2){A}
    \tkzDrawPoint(A)
}

% Axes
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, -4/0/Y, 0/-4/Z}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](Y){\huge $y$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below](Z){\huge $z$}

\tkzDrawSegments[line width=2pt,->](O,Y O,Z)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question is similar, but the answers dont use `multirow` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30488/image-dropping-down-in-multirow-table

Comment: I don't understand your question; `\multirow` places the material without performing any scaling; since you are usng `\multirow{2}{*}{...}`, the *width* of the merged cell will be the natural width of the image, but the *height* of the merged cell is still the same as it was without the image so if you don't reduce the size of the image, the image will protrude and you will get an overfull `\vbox` warning.

Comment: I see. So multirow works only horizontally, not vertically. I haven't realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround I've just seen possible, without modifying the graphics, is this:

- Include package `bigstrut`
- Use the other parameters of `multirow`:

  - *bigstruts*: value **2**.
  - *fixup*: value **2mm**
- Add a call of `\bigstrut` for each row being spanned.
- Increasing `\arraystretch` to **3**.

The code for the main `tex` file is this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabu}{ccc}
    \toprule
    Sections & Axis & Imperfections\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}[2]{*}[2mm]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{circular_hollow.pdf}} & $y-y$ & $\dfrac{L}{200}$ \bigstrut \\
                                                                              & $z-z$ & $\dfrac{L}{150}$ \bigstrut \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work for arbitrary width values, but it works. If nothing else comes up, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 7):

For those wondering how to put images in tables in general, the salient point is the bracketed fixup after the `{*}` in `\multirow`:

```
\multirow{2}{*}[fixup]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{...}}
```

For example:

```
\multirow{2}{*}[0.5in]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{...}}
```

By adjusting the fixup you can avoid Latex's default behavior of putting the image way too low in the table.