# rotate text in multirow table of figures

Tags: graphics, rotating, include, multirow

My question is similar to this one:
[How to rotate text in multirow table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table?rq=1)
but my table is composed of individual .eps files (which are all the same size, created in a different program) via \includegraphics.  I want to rotate the text in column one of the table to serve as an overall y-axis label.  However, I can't figure out how to align it properly.

My output currently has the desired y-axis label too low, ending about at the middle rather than centered vertically.  I can adjust the placement manually using the fixup parameter described at the bottom here: [Placing a figure inside a multirow table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66702/placing-a-figure-inside-a-multirow-table-cell) but it would be great if I could do this programmatically.

In case it matters, my actual table consists of 8 panels in two rows and four columns (plus an additional column/row for the overall axis labels).
Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\scale}{0.8}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2\tabcolsep}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}cc}
\parbox[t]{0.25in}{\multirow{2}{*}[0.8in]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Large dM/dlnD$_p$ ($\mu$g m$^{-3}$)}}} & 
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image1} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image2}\\
& \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image3} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{image4}\\
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large Aerodynamic diameter ($\mu$m)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm really unclear what you're asking for.  You are already using `\rotatebox`, which would be my recommendation.  So, how is this not achieving the effect you want?

Comment: The text within \rotatebox is not centered in the overall 2x2 table of figures.  At least, not without manual adjustment via the fixup parameter.

Comment: Since I don't have access to your images, I replaced them with images from the mwe package, and it looked fine.  Perhaps you images are assymetrical.

Comment: I did not know about the existence of the mwe package.  Here is a new example.

Comment: Thanks @John.  In  this line: `\parbox[t]{0.25in}{\multirow{2}{*}[0.8in]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Large dM/dlnD$_p$ ($\mu$g m$^{-3}$)}}} &` 
the [0.8in] is a fixup parameter, adjusted by trial and error.  Take it out and you'll see the misalignment I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need a fixup, but you can compute it rather than use trial and error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempdima}
\newlength{\tempdimb}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\scale}{0.5}

% get size of multicol
\settoheight{\tempdima}{\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-c} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image}
\end{tabular}}
%subtract width of text
\settowidth{\tempdimb}{\Large dM/dlnD$_p$ ($\mu$g m$^{-3}$)}
\addtolength{\tempdima}{-\tempdimb}

\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25in}@{}cc}
 \multirow{2}{*}[0.5\tempdima]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\Large dM/dlnD$_p$ ($\mu$g m$^{-3}$)}} & 
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-a} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-b}\\
& \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image-c} &
  \includegraphics[scale=\scale]{example-image}\\
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\Large Aerodynamic diameter ($\mu$m)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: The original calculation looked good, but was in fact incorrect.  Basically one needs to use the height a bottom aligned tabular (or add the depth), subtract the width of the text, then divide by two.